# $\forall A\subset \mathbb{N}$ the sum of the reciprocals of $A$ diverges iff $A$ is $(\tau, \mathbb{N})$-dense

Tags: general-topology, elementary-number-theory

Show that is possible to endow the natural numbers with a topology $\tau$ such that for every $A\subset \mathbb{N}$ the sum of the reciprocals of $A$ diverges iff $A$ is $(\tau, \mathbb{N})$-dense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hint*:

A nonempty subset $U$ of $\Bbb N$ is open iff
$$\sum_{n\notin U}\frac1n<\infty$$