# What is a topology minus the axiom that $\varnothing \in \tau$.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-number-theory, axioms

For instance, this is the case with defining $U \subset \Bbb{N}$ to be open iff $\sum_{x \notin U} \frac{1}{x} \lt \infty$ if we let $\sum_{x \notin \Bbb{N}} = 0$.  I can't seem to get $\varnothing$ to be part of that "topology" as $\sum_{x \in \Bbb{N}} = \infty$.  So what is this "pseudo-topology" called?

Please also see and comment on this post:
[$\forall A\subset \mathbb{N}$ the sum of the reciprocals of $A$ diverges iff $A$ is $(\tau, \mathbb{N})$-dense](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1368257/forall-a-subset-mathbbn-the-sum-of-the-reciprocals-of-a-diverges-iff-a)

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thanks.  What is your thought of this post, then?  It seems like it was answered, but according to your comment, it can't be answered like that: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1368257/forall-a-subset-mathbbn-the-sum-of-the-reciprocals-of-a-diverges-iff-a

Comment: My point was that you've made an error in your analysis. The empty sum is zero, so the empty set is trivially in the topology.

Comment: @CameronWilliams $\sum_{x \notin \varnothing = x \in \Bbb{N}} \frac{1}{x} = \infty$ QED --+-( '_' )-.

Comment: @CameronWilliams the sum associated to the emptyset is $\sum_{x\not\in\emptyset}1\over x=\sum_{x\in\mathbb{N}} 1\over x=\infty$; I believe you misread the definition.

Comment: Ohhhhh. My bad. I didn't realize it was $x\not\in U$.

Comment: Sometimes, you have to artificially add in $\varnothing$ to make a topology.  So, you would define $\tau$ by the property that $\varnothing \in \tau$ and for any $U \ne \varnothing$, $U \in \tau$ (it's open) if and only if $\sum_{x \not\in U} \frac{1}{x} < \infty$.

Comment: If you didn't have that the empty set was part of the set of "open" sets (or whatever you want to call them), you have to modify the definition a bit. You can't have empty unions but you also have to change the intersection property to say that *if* two "open" sets have nontrivial intersection, then their intersection is in the set. Neither of these are very significant adaptations, though, and I suspect you could probably still do a lot with this sort of definition of a quasi-topology. However you'd probably have to say "assume that the intersection is nonempty" yadda yadda yadda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, the fact that the emptyset is not "open" is the only barrier to your definition yielding a topology. Closure under arbitrary nonempty unions is obvious; to see that the intersection of two "opens" is "open," let $S_X=\sum_{n\not\in X}{1\over n}$; then note that $$S_{X\cap Y}\le S_X+S_Y<\infty$$ if $S_X, S_Y<\infty$. In such situations as these, it's common to just add the emptyset so you get a genuine topology. Since this is really a trivial modification, I don't believe there is a name for someething which would be a topology if it contained $\emptyset$ (that is, for a family of subsets of some set $X$ which is closed under arbitrary nonempty unions, finite intersections, and contains $X$ itself).

Comment: This is more or less what @ajotatxe hinted at in their answer on the other question. A *nonempty* subset $U$ of $U$ is open if and only if the sum of the reciprocals in $\mathbb{N}\setminus U$ is finite.

Comment: Well, you don't get closure under *arbitrary* unions, because you don't have the empty union.

Comment: @GregoryJ.Puleo Quite right :P, fixed.

Comment: I think this modified "topology" would still give plenty of the same results. I discussed it in the comments above. You'd have to make some rather annoying comments about making sure the intersections are nonempty, but.. perhaps that's all. Of course that's really unsatisfactory and makes theorem statements unnecessarily long.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Quite right, I was having a silly moment.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Not at all. I actually had never really considered what happens if you remove the empty set. It's a little alarming how little things seemingly change.